# A regular link with _blank gets opened in tab but a JS window.open(url, "_blank"); open a new window?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, response.redirect

When i use regular links with `target="_blank"` i get a new tab opened but when i use a JS  `window.open(url, "_blank");` i get a new window instead(im using it from a Response.Write()), same browser same settings, why? I need the JS to react the same way as the link!

Comment: Basically this is not possible - or else you can crash the browser by opening 1000 tabs in not time, as they do the old days with the window.open, and now if you try to use it more than ones is blocked. The window.open is works like a new dialog in a sense, but the new tab is a feature of the browser to help the user, but when the user make the click is knows where to look - if you make it automatically you can create hidden pages in the tabs that the user can discover later. Not good user interface ether. Find some other way.

Comment: I got it sorted in another way, the links was generated and i got it set with an input parameter to the XSL/XML instead

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting the link into the page and setting it's style so that it is hidden from the viewport. You would then, instead of `window.open(url, "_blank");`, call `$( 'link-selector' ).click();`. Note that I haven't tested it, maybe some browsers will block the new tab from being opened.

Comment: Its not possible for me to put the link on the webbpage and then click it by the ID or something, i really need to send the url with the javascript or something similar that works for me.

Comment: When you call the click, you not actually click the link, but you run the click function that exist on the `onclick`